# Razor Pages - Create unique identifier for controls in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreach, .net-core, razor-pages

How can I create a unique name referance for a set of checkboxs when using foreach loop?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.myClass.Where(i => i.ID1 == 0))
{
  <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Stuff" />
  <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Stuff" />
  <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Stuff" />
}
```

**HTML (Output)**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="item_Stuff" name="item_Stuff">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="item_Stuff" name="item_Stuff">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="item_Stuff" name="item_Stuff">
```

---

I have seen the Razor Pages recommendation [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding) however this recommends using for loop or explicit indexing and this wont work in my case because I need the where clause on my statement.

**EXAMPLE**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="Contacts[i].FirstName" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="Contacts[i].LastName" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="Contacts[i].Email" />
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: you could try using htmlhelpers instead of tag helpers, also even with foreach you can use a integer counter to generate them with no issue.

Comment: @{var i=0;} @foreach(var item in collection){<input type="text" name="item[@i].stuff" />++i;} see how i am doing this html way and not using tag helper

Comment: @Alok Thanks. I can actually achieve what I need using standard html already I am new to tag helpers and thought there where great until they failed to do this simple task. Do you recommend not bothering with tag helpers in cases like this?

Comment: even though you can do some extensions it not worth it to invest such time on simple stuff already available in html, plus if you use direct html where you know things wont go complex it will also save you performance needed for asp tag to transform into html page output

Comment: @Alok I think you are correct. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: as for tag helpers we have both htmlhelpers and tag helpers , so what you cant do in one can do in another see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-2.2 hope this will be useful in your future journey

Comment: IMO, tag helpers are pretty easy to use. You just need to know how to use them. Performance should never be a consideration. I wouldn't use Html helpers in .NET Core at all. Tag helpers were introduced to replace them.

Comment: You cannot do this. Any filtering of your set in the view will throw off the model binding. You'll never be able to get this to work as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you feel the urge to put counter variables in a content page or view, that's an indication that you are doing something sub-optimal. It's a code smell.

What I would do to minimise the code in the *.cshtml* file is filter the items in the PageModel. I would add another property:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    public List<MyClass> Entities { get; set; } = new List<MyClass>();
    public List<MyClass> EntitiesWithNoId => Entities.Where(e => e.ID == 0);
    // blah blah
}
```

Then in the content page:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.EntitiesWithNoId.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="EntitiesWithNoId[i].FirstName" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="EntitiesWithNoId[i].LastName" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" asp-for="EntitiesWithNoId[i].Email" />
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

That is an example of utilising the ViewModel aspect of the PageModel. Part of it's role is to act as a place to prepare data for the view.